# SQL Server Cumulative Sum breaks

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, cumulative-sum

I have one Amount field and I want to build the following table (CumulativeSum and GroupNo columns):

```
| Id | Amount | CumulativeSum | GroupNo |

| 1  | 1000   | 1000          | 0       |
| 2  | 2000   | 3000          | 0       |
| 3  | 1000   | 4000          | 0       |
| 4  | 3000   | 3000          | 1       |
| 5  | 2000   | 5000          | 1       |
| 6  | 3000   | 3000          | 2       |
| 7  | 1000   | 4000          | 2       |
| 8  | 4000   | 4000          | 3       |
| 9  | 2000   | 2000          | 4       |
```

Note: when ever the CumulativeSum becomes grater than 5000, I need it to start summing from 0 with a new Group Number (GroupNo).

For Example the sum of rows 1, 2 and 3 equals 4000. The amount of row 4 is 3000 and 4000 + 3000 = 7000 and it is grater than 5000 so it must break and start from 0 again.

Comment: A cumulative sum itself is easy. Having some breaks in it so it start from 0 every time it reaches a specific sum, I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a recursive CTE. These are effectively loops, where the next value is calculated based on previous values. Here's a link to a basic example and writeup of how they work: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

In this case, it checks if the previous value + the current value is over 5000; if so, it resets the counter and adds 1 to the GroupNo; otherwise it just adds the current value to CumulativeSum.

```
CREATE TABLE #Amts (ID int PRIMARY KEY, Amount int);
INSERT INTO #Amts (ID, Amount)
VALUES
(1, 1000),    --  | 1000  | 0 |
(2, 2000),    --  | 3000  | 0 |
(3, 1000),    --  | 4000  | 0 |
(4, 3000),    --  | 3000  | 1 |
(5, 2000),    --  | 5000  | 1 |
(6, 3000),    --  | 3000  | 2 |
(7, 1000),    --  | 4000  | 2 |
(8, 4000),    --  | 4000  | 3 |
(9, 2000);    --  | 2000  | 4 |

WITH RunningTotals AS
    (SELECT A.ID, A.Amount, A.Amount AS CumulativeSum, 0 AS GroupNo
     FROM #Amts A
     WHERE ID = 1
     
     UNION ALL

     SELECT RT.ID + 1,
            A.Amount, 
            CASE WHEN RT.CumulativeSum + A.Amount > 5000 THEN A.Amount 
                ELSE RT.CumulativeSum + A.Amount END,
            CASE WHEN RT.CumulativeSum + A.Amount > 5000 THEN RT.GroupNo + 1
                ELSE RT.GroupNo END
     FROM RunningTotals RT
          INNER JOIN #Amts A ON RT.ID + 1 = A.ID
    )
SELECT  *
    FROM RunningTotals
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

Results are as follows

```
ID  Amount  CumulativeSum  GroupNo
1   1000    1000           0
2   2000    3000           0
3   1000    4000           0
4   3000    3000           1
5   2000    5000           1
6   3000    3000           2
7   1000    4000           2
8   4000    4000           3
9   2000    2000           4
```

Notes

- This currently requires the IDs to be consecutive and starting with 1. If not, you may need to make an initial CTE with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id)` to get this
- I've put MAXRECURSION 1000 on there - that means it will do this looping 1000 times. If you have a larger table than this, you'll need to increase that number.

Update: fixed bug in code ( `RT.GroupNo + 1` was in wrong spot). Also added 'Amount' column to output.